# R: detect changing characters without loop

Tags: r, loops, character

I'm analyzing a huge dataset of ~700000 rows.

I would like to detect where (in which rows) the character change from previous one without using loops.

For instance, in the array "dat", the ideal function would give `c(4,6)`

```
dat=c(BIS84003, BIS84003, BIS84003, BIS84005, BIS84005, BIS84006)
```

Does someone has any idea?

Comment: For future reference, `dat` is a `vector`, not an `array`, since you don't have a second dimension.  What you call "rows" are `elements` of the `vector` . The word "row" is used to refer to the `[j,]` collection of elements in a matrix or array.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of doing this:

1. Use run-length encoding
2. Directly compare vectors

Method 1: Use run length encoding with the function `rle()`.

```
dat=c("BIS84003", "BIS84003", "BIS84003", "BIS84005", "BIS84005", "BIS84006")
head(cumsum(rle(dat)$lengths) + 1, -1)
[1] 4 6
```

Method 2: compare vectors

```
1 + which(dat[-1] != dat[-length(dat)])
[1] 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `diff`

```
 which(!!c(0,diff(as.numeric(factor(dat)))))
 #[1] 4 6
```